# com.google.android.gms E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released

Tags: android

I have an android app which is currently in the play store that I am working on an upgrade for, including targeting the new Android O. I was also expecting Android 5 to have some sort of issue as I've seen Android 5 in my developer console having a much higher uninstall rate compared to other android versions - but the odd thing is I am never reciving a crash either from the Play Developer Console or the Firebase Crash.

I'm working my way through testing on each android Version from O downwards and everything is fine, except on Lollipop 5.0 where as soon as the main activity launches it crashes, but the crash is coming internally within SQLite or ParcelFileDescriptor, not within my code.

When the app launches, it launches an EULA activity which is fine, and it then starts an intent to the Main Activity.

When this launches, it does an HTTP post to check the API status, and looks up the apps sqlite database to create the navigation drawer.

I've turned bot of these off, so all it is now doing is starting the main activity and setting the layout and creating the objects of the various controls (i.e. calling findViewById).

Below is my main activities onCreate method

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        logAmplitudeEvent("MainActivity");

        //Initialise Mobile Ads
        MobileAds.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "adb-mob-id");

        Amplitude.getInstance().logEvent("App Started");


        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setElevation(toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        commonTasks = new CommonTasks(this);




        iapManager = new IAPManager(getApplicationContext());
        iapManager.createIAPServiceBinding();

        SharedPreferences settings = commonTasks.getAppsSharedPreferences();
        if (!settings.getBoolean("V18AppThemeFixed", false))
        {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            if (settings.getInt(Defines.SharedPreferenceSettings.APPLICATION_THEME, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light)
                    == android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light)
            {
                editor.putInt(Defines.SharedPreferenceSettings.APPLICATION_THEME, com.BoardiesITSolutions.Library.R.style.LibAppTheme);
            }
            else
            {
                editor.putInt(Defines.SharedPreferenceSettings.APPLICATION_THEME, com.BoardiesITSolutions.Library.R.style.LibAppThemeDark);
            }
            editor.putBoolean("V18AppThemeFixed", true);
            editor.apply();
        }


        FragmentTransaction t = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment mainContentFragment = new MainContentFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.content_frame, mainContentFragment, "MainContentFrag");
        t.commit();


        mDrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerNav = findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        //NavigationMenuHelper navMenuHelper = new NavigationMenuHelper(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this,
        //        mDrawerLayout, mDrawerNav);

        //NavigationManagerAdapter menuAdapter = navMenuHelper.getMenuItems();

        //mDrawerNav.setAdapter(menuAdapter);

        AppCompatNavigationManager navManager = new AppCompatNavigationManager(this, mDrawerLayout);

        mDrawerToggle = navManager.setDrawerToggle(toolbar);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        navManager.prepareActionBar();

        //ChangeLogManager whatsNew = new ChangeLogManager(this);
        //whatsNew.showWhatsNew();
        //getAPIStatus();

    }
```

Below is the stacktrace from logcat

```
com.google.android.gms E/StrictMode: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
                                                                  java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
                                                                      at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
                                                                      at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
                                                                      at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:169)
                                                                      at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:363)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.l.a(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.l.writeToParcel(:com.google.android.gms:5)
                                                                      at kyv.a(:com.google.android.gms:16)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.d.writeToParcel(:com.google.android.gms:28)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.j.a(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.request.service.i.run(:com.google.android.gms:7)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.v.call(:com.google.android.gms:1)
                                                                      at com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.util.w.run(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-02 19:18:33.999 22599-22631/com.mycompany.myapp E/chromium: [ERROR:gl_renderer.cc(445)] Reached limit of pending sync queries.
07-02 19:18:34.004 22599-22631/com.mycompany.myapp A/chromium: [FATAL:gles2_implementation.cc(3487)] Check failed: query->CheckResultsAvailable(helper_). 
07-02 19:18:34.004 22599-22631/com.mycompany.myapp A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 22631 (RenderThread)
07-02 19:18:34.256 1587-1692/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '22a5bdc4 com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-02 19:18:34.256 1587-1692/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '1f70c23d com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.Agreement (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-02 19:18:34.256 1587-1692/system_process E/InputDispatcher: channel '1120231d com.mycompany.myapp/com.mycompany.myapp.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
07-02 19:18:36.621 1202-1202/? E/installd: eof
07-02 19:18:36.621 1202-1202/? E/installd: failed to read size
```

I'm using the Android x86 and I've also tried the android_x86_64 android 5.0 emulator image. Has anyone else seen anything like this, is it possible that this is a bug in the emulator image - although I'm assuming this is unlikely.

Comment: Looks like a bug in your ad library. Not much you can do about that, other than make sure you are on the latest version of that library, then file a bug report with the library developer.

Comment: Ah yes, missed it was coming from the ads library, that's annoying. I've ended up wrapping my ad request in a if not lollipop get an ad. Its rather odd though I didn't receive any crash details on the play developer console, i even get the odd crash when its a kernel crash so surprised this one didn't come through